# Simulator is Not Loading in Eclipse

Tags: android

I have installed Android SDK, Linux Helios 3.6.2, and ADT plugin in my fedora 13 linux machine. When I am trying to run an application, the simulator is not loading. Anybody know what is the issue, is this any permission issue?

Help is highly appriciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

delete current simulator & create new one with lesser memory